# Rspec test fails

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I am trying to test `#game_over?` method in which it calls `#check_row` in `Board` class using an `instance_double` but the test fails. Here is the test:

```rb
describe '#game_over' do
    subject(:game_over) { described_class.new }
    let(:board) { instance_double(Board) }
    context 'when #game_over is called' do
      it 'calls #check_row in Board' do
        game_over.game_over?
        expect(board).to receive(:check_row)
        #game_over.game_over?
      end
    end
  end
```

I was expecting the `#game_over?` to call `#check_row` in `Board` class but the test fails. Here is the method I am testing:

```rb
 def game_over?
    return true if @board.check_row || @board.check_column || @board.check_diagonal || @board.check_antidiagonal

    false
  end
```

Here is the failure message:

```
  1) Game#game_over when #game_over is called calls #check_row in Board
     Failure/Error: expect(board).to receive(:check_row)
     
       (InstanceDouble(Board) (anonymous)).check_row(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Here is my `Game` `#initialize` method:

```rb
  def initialize
    @board = Board.new
  end
```

Comment: You have to run `game_over?` **first**, and **then** can expect that the method is called. The method is not called before you run it.

Comment: How do you initialize `@board` in your `Game` class. Hint: `@board` in your game class and `board` in your test are likely totally unrelated instances.

Comment: @user1934428 I have tried that but it still fails

Comment: Then update your question with this modification. We can only discuss the code you have in your question, and in that code you posted, it is clear that the expect must fail.

Comment: @spickermann yes, they are different. `board` in my test is an `instance_double` while `@board` in `Game` class is an instance of `Board` class

Comment: That is not the point, the test still calls the normal instance of Board in the Game and not your mock, because you never replaces the normal board instance in the game with the mock from the test. Please share your Game class and how you initialize the board in the Game class, then we might be able to help you how to fix your test.

Comment: Aside from this, you indeed never invoke `board.check_row` anyway. You could do a `expect(game_over.instance_eval { @board }).to receive(:check_row)` instead.

Comment: @user1934428 but the `#game_over?` method invokes it

Comment: `game_over` invokes this method on its instance variable `@board`, but not to the variable `board` you are refering to in your `expect` statement.

Comment: @user1934428 should I test the instance variable `@board` instead if it's receiving `#check_row` method call?

Comment: Read my comment which makes one concrete proposal of exactly what you are asking here. Not knowing how your `game_over.class` looks like, I can't suggest anything better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance of `Board` in your `Game` class and the board mock in your test are different instances and therefore the test fails.

I suggest using dependency injection to be able to control the board instance in the `Game` and change your initializer and your test like this:

```
# in the Game class
def initialize(board = nil)
  @board = board || Board.new
end

# in your spec
describe '#game_over?' do
  subject(:game) { described_class.new(board) } # inject the board stub here
  
  let(:board) { instance_double(Board) }

  before { allow(board).to receive(:check_row).and_return(true) } 

  it 'delegates to Board#check_row' do
    game.game_over?
    
    expect(board).to have_received(:check_row)
  end
end
```

---

Note:

I would argue that the test in its current form doesn't add much value and that it tests an internal implementation detail that you should not really care about.

There is no benefit in testing that a specific method is called on an internal `@board` object in the `Game`. In fact, testing such internal behavior will make it more difficult to refactor the code later on when requirements changed or new features are implemented.

Instead, I suggest focusing on testing that the method returns the expected result under certain preconditions (but not if and how the result is received from another object).

In this example, I suggest not testing that `board.check_row` was called, but that `Board#game_over?` returns the expected result because of the call) like this:

```
# in the Game class
def initialize(board = nil)
  @board = board || Board.new
end

# in your spec
describe '#game_over?' do
  subject(:game) { described_class.new(board) }    # inject the board stub here
  
  let(:board) { instance_double(Board) }

  context 'with the board row check returns true' do
    before { allow(board).to receive(:check_row).and_return(true) }

    it 'is game over' do
      expect(game).to be_game_over
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am stuck if I should edit my `Game` class or just test the instance variable `@board` if it's receiving a `#check_row` method call?

Comment: This works but I went with testing the instance variable instead

Comment: I would change the Game class and allow the dependency injection. I would consider reading and modifying internal instance variables from the outside a code smell.